# When does EE FPC expire?

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

Does anyone know how to tell what the **lifetime** is in on the **enterprise edition** **`full page cache`**? I've poked around the code base a good bit but I don't see anything that indicates a **set lifetime**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will use the default from Mage_Core_Model_Cache::DEFAULT_LIFETIME which is 7200 seconds.

Take a look at the `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()` method. It will either create its own instance of a `core/cache` model or use the application's if there are no specific options set.

Comment: Are you following me? :) Thanks! This sounds accurate, but I'll verify tonight.

Answer (score 6):

In the `<full_page_cache>` tag in your `./app/etc/local.xml` just define

```
<lifetimelimit>86400</lifetimelimit>
```

The lifetime is defined in seconds. You need to strike a balance between content freshness, performance and the amount of storage space you actually have available.

The default is 7200 seconds.

Comment: Great answer! I'm accepting beeplogic's just because he answered me first. Thanks for the lifetime tip!

Comment: AFAIK this does only apply when you are using Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis, and it needs to be placed `<full_page_cache><backend_options> HERE </backend_options><full_page_cache>`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I've been doing a lot of work with FPC recently and I wanted to clarify because the above is not accurate. Magento EE FPC out of box does *not* support expiration.

`Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor::processRequestResponse()` does this...

`$cacheInstance->save($content, $cacheId, $this->getRequestTags());`

Since lifetime is not passed here it defaults to `null`. See `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::save()` signature...

`public function save($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifeTime = null)`

Also of note https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/pull/77