# Magento Full Page Cache Expires in 2 hours

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

Is there any idea why Magento Enterprise Full Page Cache Expires in 2 hours ?

[When does EE FPC expire?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/741/when-does-ee-fpc-expire) 
I found this link , but i dont know what exact code i need to put in local.xml.
Is there any other settings that solves the Full page cache expire issue?

Thanks

Comment: what cache backend do you use and how did you configure that `full_page_cache` node in local.xml?

Comment: For Default Magento enterprise  I changed it here:
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php: const DEFAULT_LIFETIME  = 86400;
The default was 7200 (2 hours) and its working fine for me

Answer (score 3):

It can depend on how your site/server was setup. That being said, in my app/etc/local.xml of a EE 1.13 site, using the built in Redis, I have the following:

```
<full_page_cache>
<backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
<backend_options>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
<port>6380</port>
<persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
<database>1</database> <!-- Separate database 1 to keep FPC separately -->
<password></password>
<force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
<connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
<lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit>    <!-- 16 hours of lifetime for cache record -->
<compress_data>0</compress_data>        <!-- DISABLE compression for EE FPC since it already uses compression -->
</backend_options>
</full_page_cache>
```

Realistically, more information will need to be known because it will depend on what kind of server you have, who your host is (and whether it is a dedicated or shared box), what caching strategies are available on the server, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We encountered server load spike every 2 hours due to clearing of cache. When it happened, it took a few minutes for the cache to repopulate and the load to settle down. As pointed out in the comment, the 2 hours constant is set at `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::DEFAULT_LIFETIME`. To change this to 24 hours, add this in *app\etc\local.xml*:

```
<global>
    <cache>
      <frontend_options>
          <lifetime>86400</lifetime>
      </frontend_options>    
    </cache>  
</global>
```